# Error when trying to round values in an ndarray

Tags: python, matrix, rounding, export-to-csv, numpy-ndarray

I am working on a memory-based collaborative filtering algorithm. I am building a matrix that I want to write into CSV file that contains three columns: `users`, `app` and `ratings`.

```
fid = fopen('pred_ratings.csv','wt');

for i=1:user_num
  for j=1:item_num
    if R(j,i) == 1
      entry = Y(j,i);
    else
      entry = round(P(j,i));
    end
    fprintf(fid,'%d %d %d\n',i,j,entry);
  end
end
fclose(fid);
```

The above code is a MATLAB implementation of writing a multidimensional matrix into a file having 3 columns. I tried to imitate this in python, using:

```
n_users=816
n_items=17
f = open("guru.txt","w+")
for i in range(1,n_users):
  for j in range(1,n_items):
      if (i,j)==1 in a:
          entry = data_matrix(j, i)
       else:
          entry = round(user_prediction(j, i))
     print(f, '%d%d%d\n', i, j, entry)
f.close
```

But this results in the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-198-7a444566e1ce>", line 7, in <module>
entry = round(user_prediction(j, i))
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Raha am getting the error when am trying to run the block of code in python.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` uses square brackets for indexing. Since `user_predictions` is a numpy array, it should be indexed as

```
user_predictions[i, j]
```

The same goes for `data_matrix`.

You should probably read the [Numpy for MATLAB users](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) guide.

Edit:
Also, the

```
if (i,j)==1 in a:
```

line is very dubious. `(i, j)` is a tuple of two integers, which means it will never be equal to `1`. That line is thus equivalent to `if False in a:` which is probably not what you want.